# Website changes size when i have smaller monitor / bigger

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this problems with my website. Im pretty new at coding, so if something is weird or stuff like that, thats maybe the reason. I coded and did go after making the website after my 17" monitor. So when I used another one, it just totally gone weird, or made it smaller on this monitor, it like push the "header" into my `h3`. And thats not how i want it to work. So i want it to stay the same way, no matter monitor size or resolutions. I tried to google but could't find my answer. Here is my following codes:

Its coded in my own language so just ignore it if you don't understand.

Comment: Can we see some code and a picture of the problem?

Comment: So i don't know why you can see the link, but here it is:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LbxVJM

Comment: There are no `<h3>`s in the code...

Comment: So it should usually look like this: https://gyazo.com/a8988ef8a20a6d6cc2d9b413487422ee But if i resize it and make my own browser smaller it looks like this: https://gyazo.com/76571c96d05106e2a4f779627e8c3161

Comment: Then h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, or h6. Whatever. It still pushes it into....

Comment: Remove `float: left;` and `position:fixed` (remove, as in code the site without them, not just delete them and nothing else)

Answer (score 0):

You can use frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) to make your elements fit in any screen sizes!

Comment: Which, while useful, is the exact opposite of what they're asking... maybe they're asking the wrong thing or looking at it at the wrong angle.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the position of `#content` to `absolute`, and setting the width of the `.boks` to `60vw` (60% of the screen width), and its position from the left to `left: 15vw;` and removing the `margin` on `.copyright`.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbdGGj

Comment: Alot of it helped, but there is still the problem with the header: https://gyazo.com/cae6390149df347f2474fa0d04aacb8c you can see it there. But thank you for the rest c:

Comment: Apply the same properties to the header

Comment: It didn't work. Still does the same. Is it a possibility, to add them into a button when it gets under a specific size? If yes, could you help me do that?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wogyOM . I changed a few of the size and position values for the header. If you want a website to look the same on all sizes of screens, then you want to only use relative units (`em`,`vw`,`vh` etc)

Comment: ty again. It works in smaller monitor sizes, or if i make my window smaller. But if i use all of my monitor, which is 27" it looks like this:https://gyazo.com/ad228a9a62baf95b43834f44ede39656 And its not supposed to do that.

Comment: Are you talking about the spacing issue between the header and the content?

Answer (score 0):

> **TL;DR**:
>
> - As you are a beginner, your site will be messy.
> - Your problems are down to the positioning of elements.
> - Try clearing up your code and use CSS for spacing instead of loads of unnecessary `&nbsp;` entities.
> - Learn responsive website development or use a pre-made framework such as Bootstrap or Foundation.
> - When using relative / fixed positioning on the same page, always use a foundation div to ensure your content doesn't float under or over another piece of content.

To answer your question, you *can keep an element of continuity* on different screen sizes, however in modern website development you're going to want to make a responsive site.

From what I can see, the problems that you are experiencing are to do with the positioning of elements and the responsiveness of them.

Invest some time into learning responsive website development. Some good resources are as follows:

- [W3Schools Responsive Design Lessons](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)
- [Code School's Journey Into Mobile Course](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/journey-into-mobile)